# Two Database tables related in two different ways...?

Tags: mysql, doctrine, rdbms, yaml

Im sort of scratching my head on this one.  Here's the scenario.  Im using Doctrine and YAML schema files:

I have a table User and a table Event

User looks like this:

```
User:
    columns:
        id:
            type: integer(7)
        email:          
            type: string(100)
        display_name:
            type: string(255)
        fb_id:
            type: string(100)
    relations:
        Event:
            type: many
            refClass: UserEvent
```

Event looks like this:

```
Event:
    columns:
        id:
            type: integer(7)
        initiator_id:          
            type: integer(7)
        loc_latitude: 
            type: decimal(11)
        loc_longitude: 
            type: decimal(11)
        4sq_id:
            type: integer(11)
    relations:
        User:
            type: one
            local: initiator_id
            foreign: id
        User:
            type: many
            refClass: UserEvent
```

As you can see the problem is this: A User (or 'initiator') can start many events, and an event can belong to one User ('initiator').  However, an event can also have many Users who join it, and a User can Join many events.

So Event and User end up being related in two different fashions.  How does this work?  Is it possible to do it this way or am i missing something?

Comment: you should write that as an answer @Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need one many-to-many relationship between the two tables. UserEvent will tell you what users have what events (and vice versa)... and joining through UserEvent and adding WHERE user.id = event.initiator_id will give you access to a user's initiated events, assuming they also belong to those events.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add an event_attendees table with the event id and user id as the two columns? Or is this not the question